# How and when to use Q_DECLARE_METATYPE

Tags: c++, qt, qmetatype

I need to cast a QSqlRecord to QVariant and back throughout my project. In order to do so I added

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QSqlRecord);
```

in the .h files of the classes which require the casting.
I also have a base class from which several children inherit, in this case I assume it is sufficient to include the Q_DECLARE_METATYPE only once in the base class. I therefore have for example:

- widgetBaseClass: declares metatype
- widgetChildClass1: inherits widgetBaseClass does not declare metatype
- widgetChildClass2: inherits widgetBaseClass does not declare metatype
- myTableModel: declares metatype

When I try to run the program like this I get

```
Redefinition of 'QMetaTypeId<QSqlRecord>
```

from widgetBaseClass, pointing to the previous declaration in myTableModel. If on the other hand I remove the declaration I get:

```
static_assert failed "Type is not registered, please use the Q_DECLARE_METATYPE macro to make it known to Qt's meta-object system");
```

From how I understand the workings of Q_DECLARE_METATYPE this means that if i declare it, it result in an error because it was already declared somewhere else, but if I don't declare it I cannot cast from QVariant, because it does not recognise the object as a valid QVariant, what am I missing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should place `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QSqlRecord)` in only one header and then just include it everywhere it is needed.

`Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QSqlRecord)` has to be outside any classes and namespaces.

[From Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html):

> *Ideally, this macro should be placed below the declaration of the class or struct. If that is not possible, it can be put in a private header file which has to be included every time that type is used in a QVariant.*

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I did place the Q_DECLARE_METATYPE outside namespaces, it is however in the .h file of another class. should I instead just create a specific .h file with all the Q_DECLARE_METATYPE I need and include that whenever i need it?

Comment: @NicoloCastro from Qt documentation >Ideally, this macro should be placed below the declaration of the class or struct. If that is not possible, it can be put in a private header file which has to be included every time that type is used in a QVariant.

Comment: Right thank you, sorry for that I skimmed through it and apparently didn't register the paragraph.

Answer (score 11):

You use `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` on classes with public constructor, destructor, copy-constructor, so QSqlRecord fits. Just make sure that this macro is used only once per class declaration. Possibly you missed some `#pragma once`?

Use it on your own classes, after declaration of the class, outside namespace braces:

```
//mystruct.h
namespace MyNamespace
{
struct MyStruct
{
    int i;
    ...
};
}

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyNamespace::MyStruct)
```

See documentation here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE

Comment: Why shouldn't I use the declare metatype on classes from Qt? How can I cast a QVariant to a Qt class? or should I not be allowed to do that?

Comment: Sorry, I refreshed my info from documentation and quickly fixed answer.

Comment: Oh ok thanks. So in the classes I write which I know I will cast i can put the declaration directly in the same file, outside of the namespace, for the others I have to include it, but here is my problem, right now if I include it it tells me it is already included (Redefinition of 'QMetaTypeId<QSqlRecord>) if i remove it, it tells me I didn't declare it.

Comment: this really looks like your .h file is missing include guards (either #pragma once  or #ifndef FILENAME #define FILENAME)